# Concepts in statistics and probability-theory: sample and observation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, terminology

I am confused regarding the terminology employed in statistics and probability-theory. Specifically, the difference (if there is any) between *sample* and *observation*. As I understand it, it goes as follows. I probably have it wrong, so please help me out here.

Assume an experiment that depends on a random process, and whose outcome is one of all the possibilities comprised in its sample space $\Omega$. For example, rolling a dice, whose outcome can be any of the six sides facing up, $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

- **Observation**: every time we run the experiment, we get an observation equal to one of the elements in the sample space $\Omega$. It is, so to say, the output of the experiment.
- **Sample**: if we run the experiment and record the observation, we are sampling (i.e. getting a sample). With each iteration, we are adding one observation to our sample, but we could also have chosen to create a sample with only one element.

**Q:** I know that a sample is a set of one or more elements from our population (even if uncountable). So, is it different from an *observation*? Does the term *observation* actually exist in this context? Which one is the correct term to use, and when?

Comment: sample = recorded observation

Comment: To study the result of one roll of a dice, $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is suitable, but not to study the result of several rolls of a dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your distinction between the words *observation* and *sample* is correct.
It is possible to have a sample consisting of one observation. (Just as
it is possible to have a set consisting of one element, but that does not
make the set and the element the same thing.)

Unfortunately, some texts and software do not adhere to your distinction.
One major software package frequently (if not consistently) refers to 'samples' when the word 'observations' is meant.

Perhaps contributing to the confusion is the terminal illness, if not
death, of the word *datum*. Originally in English, the word *data* was the plural of *datum.*
Nowadays there seems to be confusion whether *data* is a singular or plural
word. To avoid confusion, some authors (myself included) ordinarily use 'observation'
for the singular and 'dataset' or 'sample' as collective nouns for a set of
observations.

In formal writing many
American authors still use *data* only as plural noun. "These are the data
from my experiment." "What do the data say?" Colloquially, a lot more
Americans are comfortable with something like "I've finished, here's the data."

From a linguistic high horse, one can deplore the disappearance of
singular 'datum' and plural 'data'. But languages change and and there is
no stopping that. It used to be that 'agendum' was an item for discussion
at a meeting and 'agenda' was a list of such items. Nowadays 'agendum'
seems to be totally dead, and not even the most fastidious American grammarians find
any fault with 'agenda' as singular: "Here is the agenda for the meeting."
(A couple of decades from now, I predict 'data' will always be singular in the US.)

Some of this may be different in the UK where collective nouns ordinarily
take plural verbs, as in "The committee are meeting now". by contrast with
American "The committee is meeting now." (often illogically followed by "They'll  be
done in 15 minutes."). I will let someone from the UK
speak to that.